# How can I parse the following Array with php?

Tags: php, regex, arrays, parsing

string: `[Name] => google [AF] => 0 [AX] => 2 [AL] => 1 [DZ] => 0 .....`

output:

```
[AX,2]
[AL,1]
```

the countries with [0] entries are being excluded in the list

```
I have tried using sql but  i want for php
Select '[AF,' + LTrim(Cast(Sum(AF) as varChar(5))) + ']' 
From Table Where name = 'Andy'
Union
Select '[AS,' + LTrim(Cast(Sum(AS) as varChar(5))) + ']' 
From Table Where name = 'Andy'
Union
Select '[AQ,' + LTrim(Cast(Sum(AQ) as varChar(5))) + ']' 
From Table Where name = 'Andy'
```

and also
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/42756/5

but i need in php

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please read http://whathaveyoutried.com

Comment: The input string kinda reminds me of `print_r` output. Where are you getting this string?

Comment: if the first string is an array it's very simple

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple foreach loop will do the trick:

```
foreach($array AS $key=>$value){
   if($value!=0){
       echo "$key,$value";
   }
}
```

Comment: thanks! used same technique